# Laravel api - how to upload file

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5, postman

I am building a web service for mobile application using Laravel. I need to let the users to upload images. I am using `passport` package. In developing environment I created a function `store` as follows

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
}
```

and using Firefox poster I post contents. These are the parameters

[image]

[image]

The problem is the function `store` always returns empty array while I expect it to return information about the file. What is wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. Firefox Poster has problems with this. I used Chrome Postman. **I removed all the headers** and set a key for file. as follows

[image]

it is header

[image]

and this is the code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    return $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning `$request` will not work. If you want to check if the file exists, try return `$request->allFiles()`

Comment: Does it display an empty array?

Comment: yes. an empty array is returned, Is there any problem with the headers?

Comment: yes, it's not reaching the backend. Probably best to try sending a file using a `FormData` object